# Custom concat (++) operator in haskell

Tags: haskell, operators

Is it possible to define my own `++` operator for a custom data type in Haskell?

I have:

```
data MyType = MyType [String]
```

and I would like to define my own concatenation operator as:

```
instance ? MyType where
    (MyType x) ++ (MyType y) = MyType (x ++ y)
```

I can't seem to find the name of the instance class anywhere.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't insist on calling the operator `(++)`,

```
import Data.Monoid

instance Monoid MyType where
    (MyType x) `mappend` (MyType y) = MyType (x ++ y)
    mempty = MyType []
```

Then you can use

```
(<>) :: Monoid m => m -> m -> m
```

which is an alias for `mappend` (I thought it was already a type class member, but it isn't :/). Lists hava a `Monoid` instance where `mappend` is `(++)`, so that would do what you desire. The `Monoid` instance also gives you

```
mconcat :: Monoid m => [m] -> m
```

which you can use to concatenate a list of `MyType`s.

Comment: that's the difference between a pro and a spare time programmer - knowing there is the `Monoid` typeclass.

Comment: Is the <> operator defined the same as the ++ operator for lists?

Comment: @WesleyTansey Yes, but I just checked and it seems that is not yet a class member in released GHC versions, so I have to slightly correct my solution.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you have an associative `(<>)` but no `mempty`, your type is probably a [semigroup](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/semigroups/latest/doc/html/Data-Semigroup.html). Unfortunately `Semigroup` isn't currently a superclass of `Monoid`.

Answer (score 4):

easiest it would be to do

```
import Prelude hiding ((++))
import qualified Prelude as P

data MyType = MyType [String]

class PlusAble a where
    infixr 5 ++
    (++) :: a -> a -> a

instance PlusAble MyType where
    (MyType x) ++ (MyType y) = MyType (x P.++ y)

-- EDIT:
instance PlusAble [a] where
    x ++ y = x P.++ y
```

Comment: This solution seems to be giving me issues with causing all other ++ operations to be ambiguous.

Comment: i think you have to add an instance for lists too - i added this in the edit

Answer (score 3):

`(++)` operator does not belong to any type class. You can easily check this:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> :info (++)
(++) :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
infixr 5 ++
```

So, it's just simple function defined in `GHC.Base` module. You can hide it and define your own one:

```
import Prelude hiding ((++))
import qualified Prelude -- to get hidden (++) as Prelude.(++)

-- your brand new (++)
infixr 5 ++
(MyType x) ++ (MyType y) = MyType (x Prelude.++ y)
```