# Haskell data type and lists

Tags: haskell

I created a datatype that is a list of other elements say

```
data Tarr = Tarr [Int] deriving (Show)
```

I would like to concatenate two of these Lists so

```
Tarr [0,2,4,2] ++ Tarr [1]
```

but I get an error

```
<interactive>:43:1:
    Couldn't match expected type `[a0]' with actual type `Tarr'
```

If there was a typeclass for (++) (Concat say) as there is for (==) (Eq) I could implement it as something like

```
class Concat a where
    (+++) :: a -> a -> a

instance Concat Tarr where 
    (+++)  (Tarr a) (Tarr b) = Tarr (a ++ b)
```

1) How should I solve my problem?

2) Any reason why `(++)` isn't defined in a typeclass?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom concat (++) operator in haskell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13595020/custom-concat-operator-in-haskell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `++` function applies to lists only, but the `<>` / `mappend` function from the Monoid typeclass generalizes it. In fact if you changed your data to a newtype instead, you could do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
import Data.Monoid

newtype Tarr = Tarr [Int] deriving (Show, Monoid)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why `(++)` isn't defined as a typeclass.  I, however, would suggest implementing a [`Monoid`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t%3aMonoid) interface for this.  I think `Monoid` is poorly named, but `mappend` and `mconcat` seem like well-known functions for concatenating things.

```
instance Monoid Tarr where
    mempty = Tarr []
    mappend (Tarr l1) (Tarr l2) = Tarr (l1 ++ l2)

Tarr [1, 2, 3] `mappend` Tarr [4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: Monoid is perfectly named, as instances of Monoid are [monoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid). `(++)` isn't defined as a typeclass because it is already generalized as `Monoid` with `(<>)`. (One could make the argument that the proper generalization is a semigroup, but that would require rearranging the typeclass hierarchy a bit.)